# How to play a movie inside a user's silhoutte using kinect

Tags: processing, kinect, simple-openni

I have created a program related to kinect in Processing IDE using SimpleOpenNI library, in which a simple image is displayed inside the user's silhouette.

This is the code:

```
depthValues=kinect.depthMap();
userMap = kinect.userMap();
for (int i =0; i < kinect.depthHeight(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < kinect.depthWidth(); j++) {
    int index=j+i*kinect.depthWidth();

  if (userMap[index] != 0) {
    c = movie.pixels[index];
 //   PImage m=movie.get();
   userImage.pixels[index]=color(c);


  }
  else{
  userImage.pixels[index]=color(0);
  }
 }      
}
```

But How can I display an image of any playing movie inside the user's silhouette ...

Can any one suggest me about this?

Comment: Isn't it just update the movie every frame? I mean you are already doing it with a single movie frame aren't you? You could also make a mask with user shape `color(255)` and use it to mask movie image

Comment: @v.k. , I tried to create a mask of a user shape , and then tried to draw a video instaed, but its not working...

Comment: OK, Is it possible to assign different images or videos to the different user's silhouettes ?

e.g, 1st user's silhouette will get 1st image, 2nd user's silhouette will get 2nd image, 3rd user's silhouette will get 3rd image, 4th user's silhouette will get 4th image ...

and so on ...